# SQL, reduce amount of repetitive formulas?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL and am just doing a bunch of select unioned together. I was wondering if there was a better way to do it in a smaller amount of code.

I'm currently doing:

```
select
   to_date('201501','YYYYMM') table_version,
   month
   sum()
   sum() 
from file_name01
group by to_date('201501','YYYYMM'), month 
union all    
 select
   to_date('201502','YYYYMM') table_version,
   month
   sum()
   sum() 
from file_name02
group by to_date('201502','YYYYMM'), month 
union all
...
```

This is repeated a bunch of times over and over again, just changing the month.
Is there a way to reduce this?

Comment: Which RDBMS / database backend are you using?

Comment: It seems to be Oracle with the `to_date`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that in! Oracle

Comment: You're not just changing the month; you're also changing the table you are selecting from each time.  Were it just the month, it would be fairly easy to help you.  As it isn't, it is much much harder.  Are you sure you can't normalize your data better -- that is, have it in a single table?  It would then be easy to fix.

Comment: Agree with @Jonathan Leffler.  If you have a bunch of tables that are identical other than the name to represent some file, why not make the filename a column in one single table instead?  Probably historical reasons you can't change that now, so no clean solution.  How many of these "file_namexx" tables are we taking about?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CTE to simplify it a bit:

```
WITH ccc AS (select to_date('201501','YYYYMM') table_version, month, xxx, yyy FROM file_name01
   union all select to_date('201502','YYYYMM') table_version, month, xxx, yyy from file_name02
   union all select to_date('201503','YYYYMM') table_version, month, xxx, yyy from file_name03
       ...etc...)
SELECT TABLE_VERSION,
       MONTH,
       SUM(xxx),
       SUM(yyy)
  FROM ccc
  GROUP BY TABLE_VERSION, MONTH
  ORDER BY TABLE_VERSION, MONTH
```

It would be simpler if you didn't put each month's data into a separate table but that may be beyond your control.

Best of luck.